# Stimulsoft Report convert normal table view To Matrix table view

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

I Use Stimulsoft and I created a report like this:
[image]

I want to combine some rows that `FirstName` and `Lastname` are same and make each unique `Status` cell as a column.

The result would be like this:
[image]

How can do this in via Stimulsoft?